# rtsp stream in opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

I'd like to read rtsp stream in my python script. To do so, I'm using OpenCV:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://name:pwd@addr:port")
```

After a while, errors pop out

```
[ WARN:0] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2060) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin
[ WARN:0] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2075) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module uridecodebin0 reported: No URI handler implemented for "rtsp".
[ WARN:0] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1053) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (616) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

and then `cap.read()` always returns `None`.

I'm not familiar with `GStreamer` and its plugins, so I didn't manage to google anything meaningful.

Comment: what is your OS? Try with: `sudo  apt-get install apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm experimenting in ubuntu docker container. I've tried to install packages, you've suggested: `apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`
Now, I can't even do `import cv2` in python interpreter:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: gst_type_find_helper_get_range_full`

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? Try to use the latest versions

Comment: I'm using `ubuntu:latest` container.
Host machine is macbook